# How to remove all white spaces if more than one

Tags: php, html, regex

I'm trying to remove all white spaces in PHP from html content if it's longer than one, per example a chain like that:

```
{{IMG}}                                     {{IMG}}                                     {{IMG}}                                     {{IMG}}                                     {{IMG}}
```

But shouldn't affect a sentence like: About us.

Should it be done with a regex? Any idea?

PS: the variable is already used with trim(); which removes white spaces at the end and at the beginning but not between characters...

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Use `trim(string);` function

Comment: You mean, like with a trim() function ?

Comment: As said **Matt Magallo** if the content is in a variable uses `trim();`

Comment: @MattMagallo trim(); removes empty spaces at the end and at the beginning so if there are white spaces between characters, they won't be removed...

Comment: are they all in a loop or array when you display `{{IMG}}`?

Comment: Yes correct they are in a foreach loop

Comment: you can use `trim($value);` in every iteration, BTW where did all the white space came from?

Comment: From parsed html code. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$str = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $originalString);
 echo $str;`

This will replace all whitespace with a single space.

Comment: Not solving the issue but found a way to make it work with your code. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Cool. Can you share what you found? It would be helpful for someone in future.

Comment: Using your code will output the following: {{IMG}} {{IMG}} {{IMG}} {{IMG}} {{IMG}} if you refer to my variable on my post, so I apply another regex: preg_replace("/}} {{/", "}}{{", $str); so I'm able to tell if the sentence is only variables or not. Thank you

Comment: @GuilVII why doesn't this solution solve your question? It does exactly what you asked. If it's now what you need then ask the correct question first.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

Example 1: Remove the whitespaces if more than 1

```
<?php
# Test variable
$string = "HELLO     I      HAVE    WHITE SPACEEE!!1";

# Count all whitespaces
# Contains more than 1 whitespace
if(substr_count($string, ' ') > 1) {
    # Example 1: Remove the whitespaces

    $string = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $string);
}
# Ouput: HELLOIHAVEWHITESPACEEE!!1
echo $string;
?>
```

Example 2: Trim the whitespaces

```
<?php
# Test variable
$string = "HELLO     I      HAVE    WHITE SPACEEE!!1";

# Count all whitespaces
# Contains more than 1 whitespace
if(substr_count($string, ' ') > 1) {
    # Example 2: Remove the whitespaces

    $string = trim($string);
}
# Ouput: HELLO I HAVE WHITE SPACEEE!!1
echo $string;
?>
```

Example 3: Replace the whitespaces

```
<?php
# Test variable
$string = "HELLO     I      HAVE    WHITE SPACEEE!!1";

# Count all whitespaces
# Contains more than 1 whitespace
if(substr_count($string, ' ') > 1) {
    # Example 1: Replace the whitespaces

    $string = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $string);
}
# Ouput: HELLO I HAVE WHITE SPACEEE!!1
echo $string;
?>
```

Example 4:

```
<?php
# Test variable
$string = "HELLO     I     HAVE     WHITE     SPACEEE!!1 And I like bananas.";

# Count all whitespaces
# Contains more than 1 whitespace
if(substr_count($string, ' ') > 1) {
    # Example 1: Replace the whitespaces

    $string = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', '', $string);
}
# Ouput: HELLOIHAVEWHITESPACEEE!!1 And I like bananas.
echo $string;
?>
```

Comment: This could work but the problem is that a sentence like "I eat bananas" contains 2 spaces and they will be removed but they should not...

Comment: @MattMagallo facepalm?

Comment: Example #2 obviously doesn't produce the output it claims. And example #1 doesn't produce the output requested in the question.

Comment: @axiac these are possible solutions, and he already found one. This answer can help also other people too, so I don't see the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather bizarre request if you ask me.

You could probably do something like (adopted from the accepted answer in case anyone else may find it useful):

```
$str = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', '', $originalString);
```

This removes all whitespaces provided there's at least 2 of them in a row.